# ReactJs adding active class to button

Tags: javascript, class, reactjs

I have five buttons, dynamically created. My target is: when any button is clicked to add active class to it, and of course if any other has that active class to remove it. How can I achieve that?

```
<div>
    {buttons.map(function (name, index) {
        return <input type="button" value={name} onClick={someFunct} key={ name }/>;
   })}
</div>
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to introduce state to your component and set it in `onClick` event handler. For example output of render method:

```
<div>
    {buttons.map(function (name, index) {
        return <input
                 type="button"
                 className={this.state.active === name ? 'active' : ''}
                 value={name}
                 onClick={() => this.someFunct(name)}
                 key={ name } />;
   })}
</div>
```

event handler (element method):

```
someFunct(name) {
    this.setState({ active: name })
}
```

Comment: @TeodorKolev maybe you should initialize state in constructor

Comment: had view so many similar question, but this is the best easiest answer so far

Answer (score 1):

One of the easiest way to add active class is setting state and changing that state on each switch, by the state value you can change the active class of the item.

I also had an same issue with switching the active class in list.

**Example:**

```
var Tags = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function(){
    return {
      selected:''
    }
  },
  setFilter: function(filter) {
    this.setState({selected  : filter})
    this.props.onChangeFilter(filter);
  },
  isActive:function(value){
    return 'btn '+((value===this.state.selected) ?'active':'default');
  },
  render: function() {
    return <div className="tags">
      <button className={this.isActive('')} onClick={this.setFilter.bind(this, '')}>All</button>
      <button className={this.isActive('male')} onClick={this.setFilter.bind(this, 'male')}>male</button>
      <button className={this.isActive('female')} onClick={this.setFilter.bind(this, 'female')}>female</button>
      <button className={this.isActive('child')} onClick={this.setFilter.bind(this, 'child')}>child</button>
      <button className={this.isActive('blonde')} onClick={this.setFilter.bind(this, 'blonde')}>blonde</button>
     </div>
  }
});
```

hope this will help you!

Answer (score 1):

**One of the ****easiest solution**** for adding active class to the current button (highlight it) for react developers.**

```js
const {useState,Fragment} = React;

const App = () => {
  const [active, setActive] = useState("");
 
  const handleClick = (event) => {
    setActive(event.target.id);
    
  }

    return (
      <Fragment>
      <button
        key={1}
        className={active === "1" ? "active" : undefined}
        id={"1"}
        onClick={handleClick}
      >
        Solution
      </button>

       <button
       key={2}
       className={active === "2" ? "active" : undefined}
       id={"2"}
       onClick={handleClick}
     >
      By
     </button>

      <button
      key={3}
      className={active === "3" ? "active" : undefined}
      id={"3"}
      onClick={handleClick}
    >
        Jamal
    </button>
</Fragment>

    );
}


 ReactDOM.render(
  <App/>,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```css
.active{
background-color:red;
}
```

```html
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
 <div id="react"></div>
```