# Set css active to onClick method

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I want to start a transition when I click on a div. Currently my transition happens only when using with css `active`. I want this transition to happen when I click on this div. How can i do that? I'm using reactjs and i think it should be done using states. But I cannot figure out how to do this.

I have done something like this but it is not working

```
<div className='vote_card_hover' style={{transform:this.state.toggle? 'translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1)':''}}>
```

I have switched style using states. when `toggle` state becomes true i'm doing the transformation. But it is not working

```css
.vote_card_hover {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height:100px;
  transition: .3s ease;
  background-color: 'red'
}

.vote_card_hover:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0);
  width: 110%;
  height: 110%;
  background: rgba(57, 161, 255, 0.5);
  transition: transform 0.5s ease;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.vote_card_hover:active:before {
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1);
}
```

```html
<div class='vote_card_hover'>
  <a>test</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ReactJs adding active class to button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38980051/reactjs-adding-active-class-to-button)

Comment: @MedetTleukabiluly It's different to what i want to do

Answer (score 0):

In this example, I made it like, the animation will keep working from the moment you click on `test`. So if you want to stop it after the first time. You can change the css property like `animation: mymove 1s 1;`.

Let me know if it wasn't your requirement.

```js
$('a').on('click', function(){
  $('.vote_card_hover').addClass('active');
})
```

```css
.vote_card_hover {

    position: absolute;
    width: 100px;
    height:100px;
    transition: .3s ease;
    background-color: 'red'

}

.vote_card_hover:before{

    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 110%;
    height: 110%;
    background: rgba(57, 161, 255, 0.5);
    transition: transform 0.5s ease;
    border-radius: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0);
}

.vote_card_hover.active:before{
    animation: mymove 1s infinite;
}
@keyframes mymove {
    0%   {transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0);}
    50%  {transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1)}
    100% {transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0);}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='vote_card_hover'>
  <a>test</a>
 </div>
```

Comment: You can toggle the state `onClick` of the `test` and apply the same class using the help of that state.