# How to add active class to clicked item in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array of objects that contain keypair values for the navbar
links, I have mapped the array to list and rendering it successful,
but when I try to add class to only active link, it is adding the
class to all the link items.

Wondering where I am going wrong?

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

class SideNavbar extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = [
      { id: 1, name: "Link1", to: "/cms", className: "side_nav_item" },
      { id: 2, name: "Link2", to: "/cms", className: "side_nav_item" },
      { id: 3, name: "Link3", to: "/cms", className: "side_nav_item" },
      { id: 4, name: "Link4", to: "/cms", className: "side_nav_item" }
    ];
  }

  handleClick = () => {
    const currentClass = document.getElementsByClassName("side_nav_item");
    for (let i = 0; i < currentClass.length; i++) {
      currentClass[i].classList.toggle("active_item");
      console.log(currentClass[i]);
    }
  };
  render() {
    const navLinks = this.state.map(link => {
      return (
        <div key={link.id}>
          <ul>
            <li onClick={this.handleClick} className={link.className}>
              <Link to={link.to}>{link.name}</Link>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      );
    });
    return <div>{navLinks}</div>;
  }
}

export default SideNavbar;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38980051/reactjs-adding-active-class-to-button

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Instead of trying to manipulate the DOM manually, you could keep a piece of state called e.g. `activeLink` that stores the id of the active link that you use that to apply the class to the active link in the render method.

**Example**

```js
class SideNavbar extends React.Component {
  state = {
    links: [
      {
        id: 1,
        name: "Link1",
        to: "/cms",
        className: "side_nav_item"
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        name: "Link2",
        to: "/cms",
        className: "side_nav_item"
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        name: "Link3",
        to: "/cms",
        className: "side_nav_item"
      },
      {
        id: 4,
        name: "Link4",
        to: "/cms",
        className: "side_nav_item"
      }
    ],
    activeLink: null
  };

  handleClick = id => {
    this.setState({ activeLink: id });
  };

  render() {
    const { links, activeLink } = this.state;

    return (
      <div>
        {links.map(link => {
          return (
            <div key={link.id}>
              <ul>
                <li
                  onClick={() => this.handleClick(link.id)}
                  className={
                    link.className +
                    (link.id === activeLink ? " active_item" : "")
                  }
                >
                  {link.name} {link.id === activeLink && "active!"}
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<SideNavbar />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: it adds active link when a link is clicked. Simple is that. You just made my day.

Comment: Question: how to active multiple items? Any clue?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is this line of code:
`const currentClass = document.getElementsByClassName('side_nav_item');`

is grabbing all your `HTML` elements with the `side_nav_items` CSS class and in *your case this is all your side nav links*. You probably want to use:

`let element = document.getElementById(id);`

to just get the side nav element which was clicked identified by it's `id`. Then you can use an `element.classList.add('active_item');` to add the `active_item` css class to the selected side nav item.

Hopefully that helps!

Answer (score -1):

I was struggling with this some time back and this solution worked for me.

import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";

const pathName = useLocation().pathname;

and then in your Link element you can simply do `className={pathName === link.to ? 'active_item' : ''}`

Comment: Welcome! 

Reviewing your answer I see you are calling a function named `useLocation`. However the code does not seem to reference any such function and you would therefore encounter an error. 

If you have a custom function with that name, be sure to include that code in your answer.