# How to know which element is selected in react and i wanna add some Styles on those element

Tags: javascript, reactjs

For Example

```
<h1>Who is your favourite teacher</>

<div className='option'>
<span>Jonas</span>
<span>andrei</span>
<span>Skhull</span>
<span>No one</span>
</div>
```

Here if the user selects any of the options I wanna add some styles to the selected Item to give a better user experience. How to implement this?

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55518798/how-to-add-active-class-to-clicked-item-in-reactjs) can help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you think about the way the example below is?

```
  const [name, setName] = useState('Jonas');
  const names = ['Jonas', 'andrei', 'Skhull', 'No one'];

  return (
      <h1>Who is your favourite teacher</h1>

      <div className="option">
        {names.map((d) => {
          return (
            <span
              className={classNames({
                selected: name === d,
              })}
              onClick={(e) => {
                e.preventDefault();
                setName(d);
              }}
              style={{marginRight: '10px', color: name === d ? 'red' : 'blue'}}>
              {d}
            </span>
          );
        })}
      </div>
     );
```

Comment: i don't get this part ```className={classNames({  selected: name === d,})}```

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/classnames 

You can install the package.
The 'classnames' package allows you to specify 'css' and 'class name' according to the conditions.

example
classNames({
   active: name===d
})

Comment: import classNames from 'classnames';
I have to make a declaration.